# Virtual Machine PostgreSQL connection

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, virtual

Есть zip-архив с виртуальной машиной. Мне дали этот архив и сказали - это виртуальная машина. Судя по названию - это PostGRE.

У меня есть DBeaver.

Как подключиться теперь к этой виртуальной машине?

Comment: А внутри архива какие расширения у файлов?

Comment: vbox, vbox-prev, vdi, log

Comment: @matrix
Установила VirtualBox, открыла vbox этой VM и запустила. И теперь такая ошибка:
'
'VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes '(VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
'Код ошибки: 
'E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент: 
'ConsoleWrap
'Интерфейс: 
'IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
'
В гугле пока нашла как исправить это, если компонент - Machine. А у меня ConsoleRap. Что делать? Как это вообще всё устроено? Не понимаю.

Comment: Нужно включить поддержку виртуализации в BIOS вашего компьютера (реального). Посмотрите вот видео, например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERnKeUMEFXU

Comment: @matrix Запустилась!!! Только внутри машины сообщение: "Ваш комп необходимо восстановить. Это 64-разрядное приложение не удалось загрузить, т.к. ваш комп-р не имеет 64-разрядного процессора. Если вы используете Windows ToGo, убедитесь, что версия Windows на вашем USB - устройстве совместима с ПК, который вы пытаетесь использовать.
Файл:\windows\system32\winload.exe
Код ошибки: 0x000035a
Вам потребуются средства восстановления на установленном носителе. Если установочный носитель (например, диск или USB- устройство) отсутствуют, обратитесь к администратору или производителю компьютера."

Comment: Я не понимаю - нужно как-то перед этим какую-то другую систем установить на виртуалку или как?

Comment: Проверьте теперь, что в настойках виртуальной машины включена аппаратная виртуализация: Система -> Ускорение -> Включить VT-x/AMD-V

Comment: @matrix там даже вкладка "Ускорение" отключена, т.е. есть, но не нажимается.

Comment: @matrix Finally, включила ускорение!  Стоит галочка! Но ошибка не исчезла ((( Та же самая ошибка - убедитесь, что версия Windows на моём USB устройстве совместима с ПК :( Может, у меня не будет это всё работать на моей Windows 10 ?? Или на моём Lenovo...

Comment: Скорее всего процессор не поддерживает аппаратную виртуализацию. Насколько я понимаю, это ноутбук? Скажите точно модель.

Comment: @matrix lenovo z500. Но не знаю насчёт не поддерживает. Я зашла в BIOS и там поменяла галочку на "Enable". Ещё по совету гугла скачала какую-то утилиту, которая мне тоже сказала, что процессор поддерживает эту штуку.... Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что не совмещаются 32-битная Windiws 7 на виртуальной машине с 64-битной Windows 10 на моём lenovo.